# View PDF files in Android webview

Tags: android

How do I open a PDF file in my web view wihtout downloading and saving it to the SD card? I have done some R&D on this but until now I haven't got any appropriate answers. Can anyone tell me how to use googledoc to open the PDF file in the web view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=link_to_pdf` will format your PDFs for you to open within the webview, using Google Docs Viewer.

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
String url = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url="+"http://sitename.com/xyz.pdf";
mWebview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview)

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ webUrl);
```

where `webUrl` is the url of the pdf you want to open.