# PDF view from String value

Tags: android

My requirement is, I need to display content in pdf for my app. I'm getting InputStream of a file over HTTP call. How can I convert this InputStream to PDF view without storing in SD card?

I can use the below code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(File Path)), "application/pdf");
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
```

But is there any other way to display in PDF?

Comment: you could try InputStream object = this.getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);

Comment: The previous comment has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way for showing PDF in android app that is embedding the PDF document to **android webview** using support from `http://docs.google.com/viewer`

pseudo

```
String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=+location to your PDF File+' 
              width='100%' height='100%' 
              style='border: none;'></iframe>";
```

a sample is is shown below

```
 String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/presentations-tips.ppt&embedded=true' 
              width='100%' height='100%' 
              style='border: none;'></iframe>";
```

Code

```
    WebView  wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); 
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.loadUrl(doc);
    //wv.loadData( doc, "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

and in manifest provide

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11718742/1450401)

Caution : I am not aware of compatibility issues with various android versions

Answer (score -1):

Try out this way:

> ```
>    File m_file=new File("/sdcard/myPdf.pdf");
>    Uri m_uri=Uri.fromFile(m_file);
>
> try
>   {
>     Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>      intentUrl.setDataAndType(m_uri, "application/pdf");
>      intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>      startActivity(intentUrl);
>    }
> catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
> {
>     Toast.makeText(m_context, "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
> ```