# How to open/display documents(.pdf, .doc) without external app?

Tags: android, pdf, external

I want to create a program, that open documents without external app. I need this, because i want to scroll the document with the phones orientation(Pitch and Roll). I create a button on the bottom of the screen, and when i hold down the button, i can scroll the document too. If i release the button, i can't scroll it. So, if i open the document with external app, my button disappears, and the sensorManager works neither.

Have someone any idea to solve this problem. Or have someone any idea, how to scroll the document, opened in an external app, with my phones orientation?

(Sorry for my English)

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.orientationscrolling"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.orientationscrolling.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
   android:id="@+id/mybutt"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="25sp"
   android:text="Scroll!!"
   android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.mybutt );

    String pdf = "http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf";
    String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.loadData( doc , "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing this issue. I couldn't load the docs in webview.

Comment: Same issue the provided solution works well for pdf files but not for .docs or .pptx files.

Comment: @karthi Did you get solved your issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you should use custom library for getting that done .See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153195/1450401) and [this](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/download)

But there is a way for displaying PDF with out calling another application

This  is a way for showing PDF in android app that is embedding the PDF document to **android webview** using support from `http://docs.google.com/viewer`

pseudo

```
String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=+location to your PDF File+' 
              width='100%' height='100%' 
              style='border: none;'></iframe>";
```

a sample is is shown below

```
 String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/presentations-tips.ppt&embedded=true' 
              width='100%' height='100%' 
              style='border: none;'></iframe>";
```

Code

```
    WebView  wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); 
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.loadUrl(doc);
    //wv.loadData( doc, "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

and in manifest provide

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11718742/1450401)

Caution : I am not aware of compatibility issues with various android versions

In this approach the drawback is you  need internet connectivity . But i think  it satisfy your need

EDIT
Try this as src for  iframe

```
src="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf"
```

try `wv.loadData( doc , "text/html",  "UTF-8");` . Both works for me

[image][image]

Comment: Impressive! I would never think on it.

Comment: i'm not sure is this you want?? because its taking support from another service

Comment: It doesn't works for some reason. Here is my phone's display picture: [link](http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=Lj6SZGXWT4)
I add permission to the manifest.
This is my Code:

'String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
  
  
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  
  webView.loadUrl(doc);'

Comment: have u given the permission in manifest ..? and in which android  version you checked it?

Comment: permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
I test it on Android 2.3

Comment: can you post the link of pdf

Comment: please give me the pdf link

Comment: String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";

Comment: i try your link it's working perfect for me on android 2.X & 4.X

Comment: if i use this, it works, but it not yours solution:
    String pdf = "http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);

Comment: and my main problem is, that i want to scroll my pdf with the phones orientatin(pitch and roll)

Comment: you said it works for you what is the matter then ??if it's work whats the problem?just want to know what went wrong

Comment: it doesn't work with your iframe solution, it works with  webView.loadUrl("docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="; + pdf url);
but it didn't solves my problem, because i cant scroll it with my phones orientation

Comment: i can't see your e-mail adress, but here is mine: buattila4@gmail.com

Comment: How can I save this pdf to phone gallery or email this pdf to a person?

Comment: It used to work previously but recently the docs.google.com/viewer?url= doesn't work. It has x-frame-options error and the pdf can't open.

Comment: How I can do with displayedArticle.getEncodedContent() ?

Comment: @delive what's displayedArticle ??

Comment: can I use this to display a pdf file from my SD card?

Answer (score 4):

Download the source code from here ([Display PDF file inside my android application](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/display-pdf-file-inside-my-android-application/))

**Add this dependency in your Grade:**

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="View PDF"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package pdfviewer.pdfviewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This library does not provide navigation for links within file. Do you know any other full-proof library with internal link navigation as well?

Comment: Sorry I don't know

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think below is the solution

```
 String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/yourfile.pdf&embedded=true' width='100%' height='100%'  style='border: none;'></iframe>";


    WebView  wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);  
    wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback()); 
    wv.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Hoping this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Above answers that are dependent on google docs will work only when you have internet connection. A better option would be to use Android [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) class.

You can try sample app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic).