# Open Pdf from url in Android application

Tags: android, pdf

I work with Android and I want to  open PDF file:

1. from  URL
2. from  Internal storage.(where put my file to Android read it?)

Can somebody help me?

Comment: hope this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14578661/1450401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming there is a PDF viewer application installed on the device**

To open the PDF in application use:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

where file is the path of PDF File.

Comment: if my phone dont have pdf viewer application installed then?