# How to open/display pdf without external app?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to display pdf file in my android app without using external intent like pdf viewer or anything else.I fount this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578530/how-to-open-display-documents-pdf-doc-without-external-app) but it uses external internet i dont want to open on internet i want to make my user view pdf in my app without using any external app..
If possible please provide me pseudo code...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk

Comment: [Native Android PDF Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/apv/) Open Source

Answer (score 1):

There are several PDF libraries, with help of them you can show PDF file in your application.

These 2 are common and often used.

1. [Native Android PDF Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/apv/)
2. [DroidReader](https://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)

[Android PDF Reader Open Source code application free Download](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.nl/2013/05/android-pdf-reader-open-source-code.html)

In this link you'll found OpenSource and free download PDF libraries.

and

[pdf-libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries)