# How to call method in android

Tags: java, android, class, call

I want to use this code from github:
https://github.com/jesperborgstrup/buzzingandroid/blob/master/src/com/buzzingandroid/tools/PDFTools.java

I want to open pdf from my website.
For example:
http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf

How can I call this method from this class?
Please explain me it like a dummy. I am beginner.

Is this correct? `PDFTools.showPDFUrl(pdf, http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf);`

Comment: `PDFTools.showPDFUrl(myContext, myPdfUrl);`

Comment: @NiekHaarman Is this correct?
`PDFTools.showPDFUrl(pdf, http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the context and url of the pdf file to the method

```
PDFTools.showPDFUrl(context, pdfUrl);
```

Comment: Is this correct? `PDFTools.showPDFUrl(pdf, http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf);`

Comment: i dont know how to write it correct. can you write me some example?

Comment: what is context? I dont know what is it... what I should write there

Comment: you are in an activity class right? suppose the activity class name is Main.java, then you can pass Main.this as first parameter

Comment: I created sample app in Android studio with Master/Detail Flow and in one detail i want to show pdf... so I am in ItemDetailFragment class.
I dont know if it is activity class. But when I write Main.java it shows me only that cannot resolve symbol... same with the name of class

Comment: i think you are in fragment class. just use getActivity() over there

Answer (score 0):

```
String pdf = "http://www.xyzwebsite.com/yourfile.pdf"; //YOUR URL TO PDF
String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+ pdfurl;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
startActivity(intent);
```

Add this permission to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

For more [Follw This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578530/how-to-open-display-documents-pdf-doc-without-external-app)