# How to create an activity that reads document files?

Tags: android, document, filereader, file-read, document-preview

This is my problem. I am creating an android app that is suppose to download documents i have stored on my server to my smart phone and opens the document WITHIN my app. So essentially I want an activity that will be able to open the document after it has been downloaded to the phone and display it in the same format it was in when it was originally uploaded. In a sense, it will act like one of those documenting reading apps that are on the play store. Thanks for any assistance.  However, users will not be able to edit the document, they will only be able to read it.

Comment: What are "document files"? Beyond that, what have you tried, and what specific problems have you encountered?

Comment: Documents files in terms of docx, pdf etc. But just docx and pdf in this case. I have been thinking but i am not sure as to what to try or what class to use to achieve this. So I tried using google to find a solution or to get an idea on what to do or try but got nothing.

Comment: `android library pdf` and `android library docx` turn up many hits in search engines.

Comment: ok will take a look at those and get back to you

Comment: after some hours of searching i still did not come across any libraries that could do what i wanted on an android device I saw some for java but none for android others i just plain did not understand. However I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578530/how-to-open-display-documents-pdf-doc-without-external-app that i think suits my needs. If there is any library that you know of that you think can help me please let me know.