# how to display online pdf file within app

Tags: android, pdf, document, pdfviewer

i need to display online pdf file in my app. i am using third party api but problem is that it's not displaying online file
here is my code

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

my xml file

```
    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and here is my final code to render online pdf file in PDFview

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf");
    mypdfview =(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);


    mypdfview.fromUri(uri)
            .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
            .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .defaultPage(0)
            .onDraw(this) // allows to draw something on a provided canvas, above the current page
            .onLoad(this) // called after document is loaded and starts to be rendered
            .onPageChange(this)
            .onPageScroll(this)
            .onError(this)
            .onRender(this) // called after document is rendered for the first time
            .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
            .password(null)
            .scrollHandle(null)
            .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
            .load();
```

i am facing problem that i can display file from asset folder. but when i passed uri then it not showing anything.
i also given internet permission and external data read permission in menifest.

Comment: I think this will help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9996059/5816000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that library doesn't allow to display remote files.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/67): Library does not support remote files, you have to download it by yourself.

You should download and store that PDF locally before trying to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Webview to load pdf

webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +pdfUrl);

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +pdfUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using some other control, you can use the webview for viewing the pdf within your application

```
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + yourURL;
String doc="<iframe src='"+url+"' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewpdf);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: yaa but using webview i cant acchive some property of pdfviewer. like zoom in and zoom out and pagechange and some other. so have to use pdfviewer.

Answer (score 1):

First you should read the file of pdf using Asynctask and then load...

Here is the code that worked for me...

Note here I am using pdfview library to show pdf

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

!!!online_pdf is the string variable which contains the Url of pdf

First make LOADURL class extending AsyncTask

```
public class LOADURL extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public LOADURL(LoadPDF loadPdf) {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(loadPdf);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching PDF from server...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
     url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200)
            {

                inputStream = new 
     BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        pdfFileName = getFileName(mypdf);
        pdfViewer.fromStream(inputStream)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(LoadPDF.this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(LoadPDF.this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(LoadPDF.this))
                .spacing(10) // in dp
                .onPageError(LoadPDF.this)
                .onError(LoadPDF.this)
                .onPageError(LoadPDF.this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
                .enableAntialiasing(true)
                .onRender(LoadPDF.this)
                .load();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}

After that call the class within onCreate View...

```
LOADURL loadurl = new LOADURL(LoadPDF.this);
loadurl.execute(online_pdf);
```

Comment: What do you do with this --- >  pdfFileName = getFileName(mypdf); ?

Comment: What is online_pdf in loadurl.execute() ?

Comment: This method is good but make very slow scroll of pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) provided by Android SDK (added in API level 21) to render PDF inside your android application. Download the PDF and save it on local storage and use below code to render it inside your app.

PdfRendererAdapter.kt

```
class PdfRendererAdapter(
private val renderer: PdfRenderer?,
private val pageWidth: Int
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PdfRendererAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val imageView: ImageView = view.imageView
    fun bind(bitmap: Bitmap) = imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
    ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.pdf_page_item, parent, false)
    )

override fun getItemCount() = renderer!!.pageCount

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentPage = renderer?.openPage(position)
    val bitmap = currentPage!!.render(pageWidth)
    holder.bind(bitmap)
}
```

}

PDFRendererExtensions.kt

```
fun PdfRenderer.Page.render(width: Int): Bitmap {
val bitmap = createBitmap(width)
render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
close()
return bitmap
}

private fun PdfRenderer.Page.createBitmap(bitmapWidth: Int): Bitmap {
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bitmapWidth, (bitmapWidth.toFloat() / width * height).toInt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
)

val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)

return bitmap
}
```

PDFRendererActivity.kt

```
class PdfRenderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var pdfRenderer: PdfRenderer? = null
private var currentPage: PdfRenderer.Page? = null
private var parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null

companion object {
    const val FILE_NAME = "testPDF.pdf"
    private const val INTENT_PDF_FILE = "pdf_file"

    fun getCallingIntent(context: Context, pdfFile: File): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(context, PdfRenderActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_PDF_FILE, pdfFile)
        return intent
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_renderer)
    openRenderer()
    showPagesInRecyclerView()
}

private fun showPagesInRecyclerView() {
    currentPage = pdfRenderer!!.openPage(0)
    val pdfAdapter = PdfRendererAdapter(renderer = pdfRenderer, pageWidth = currentPage!!.width)
    currentPage!!.close()
    pdf_rv.adapter = pdfAdapter
    pdf_rv.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
}

public override fun onStop() {
    try {
        closeRenderer()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    super.onStop()
}

private fun openRenderer() {
    val file = intent.extras?.get(INTENT_PDF_FILE) as File
    parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
    if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
        pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor!!)
    }
}

private fun closeRenderer() {
    pdfRenderer!!.close()
    parcelFileDescriptor!!.close()
}
}
```

Comment: Do not post a link to a tool or library as an answer. Demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. Do [edit] the answer, and flag for undeletion once you have added the demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you [How to open/display documents(.pdf, .doc) without external app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578530/how-to-open-display-documents-pdf-doc-without-external-app)

Add this dependency in your Grade:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="View PDF"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think its load pdf from asset folder. i need to show pdf from server

Comment: try to understand the question

Comment: this lib doesn't support online pdf.

Comment: How to open a pdf from downloads folder ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a best way to load remote pdf in app

```
 WebView  wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
       String src="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tuloenaseerapp.appspot.com/o/2_arsh_e_naaz_hq_compressed.pdf?alt=media&token=607c124b-ac28-4560-9854-1fe7d023f813";
        wv.loadUrl(src);
```