# Opening a tab with a PDF attachment in a Webview

Tags: android, pdf

We are trying to allow our users to download / display PDF files in a web application (WebView)

The HTML is a simple

```
<iframe src="path/to/pdf" />
```

**In a standard android browser everything works** - when clicking the link, the browser is allowing either display the PDF, or download... (content-type is application/pdf)

**When using the webview we do not get the same results** - a blank page is showing, (maybe a new tab is not opening correctly?!)

Note - We cannot use Google Viewer - the PDF is in a user restricted area (a session is required) - and so we cannot provide a public link to the PDF, which is required for google viewer to work.

How can we make the webview work just like the regular browser?

Comment: what you tried so far post your code along with question.

Comment: the code is a simple webview opening an html page, which contains an iframe with src set to the PDF location... works in a regular mobile browser, not working in the webview

Comment: did you tired this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578530/how-to-open-display-documents-pdf-doc-without-external-app

Comment: This is using google docs viewer, we cannot use this. why isn't the webview interacting with the PDF like the regular android browser?

Comment: check another answer someone is suggesting custom lib.

Comment: The custom library suggested isn't good enough, check the comments. - besides, why use a custom lib when the regular browser is interacting with the PDF just fine? what is the difference? - thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

HTML is simple but it contains many css, javascript/jquery code dependencies. Which browser renders accordingly and javascript can run on browsers. As browsers are preconfigured to run javascript and render html css.

---

Android webview is not preconfigured to run javascript, css. It can render html only. So it looks weird in webview as it renders without css and does not run javascript

---

How to configure webview to run css and javascript, allow go forward in webview and go backword like browser?

Here are full properties listed. [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Then your webview can let users download the file present there..

---

```
WebView mWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient((Activity)mContext));
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new testClass(), "jsinterface");
mWebView.loadUrl("UrlToLoad");
```

Answer (score 0):

> > You need to append http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= to open PDF file in Webview

```
String docInitialUrl = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+docUrl;
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(100);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(docInitialUrl);
```