# load images from sdcard in webview

Tags: android, excel, webview

hi i want to load sdcard images to webview, here is an example for load pdf (with pdfjs (javascrip lib)) in webview:
[Open PDF in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview)
is there any way like this to load jpg,tiff,png into webview? how about excel?

Comment: You want to open an SD Card (in an Android) with Excel (installed on an Android)??

Comment: no, open excel file or image in webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your first question : [ **How to load images from sdcard in to Webview ?** ] Use this code and please read the **comments** :

```java
wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
        String SdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

        // Image path [List]
        // Path => [/storage/emulated/0/files.jpg, png , tiff and etc ...]
        String Jpg = "file://"+ SdCard + "/image1.jpg"; // First Image - Jpg format
        String Png = "file://"+ SdCard + "/image2.png"; // Second Image - Png format
        String Tiff = "file://"+ SdCard + "/image3.tiff"; // Third Image - Tiff format

        // Load Images [WebView content]
        String Html = 
        "<tr><td> First Image content : </td><img src=\""+Jpg+"\"height=\"130px"+"\"width=\"100%"+"\"></tr>" +
        "<br/><hr>" +
        "<tr><td> Second Image content : </td><img src=\""+Png+"\"height=\"130px"+"\"width=\"100%"+"\"></tr>"+
        "<br/><hr>" +
        "<tr><td> Third Image content : </td><img src=\""+Tiff+"\"height=\"130px"+"\"width=\"100%"+"\"></tr>";

        // local html
        wbView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",Html, "text/html","utf-8", "");

        //wbView.loadUrl(""); <== Do not use this !
```

**Do not forget** to add these permissions in your manifest file :

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Output Image** [WebView] :

[image]

And unfortunately I did not find the answer for your second question [Excel] , if I find a way, I'll tell you :)

Good luck.