# Load sdcard pdf files in Webview in android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am trying to display `multiple pdf files in ViewPager` using web view.

I am able to fetch the path of pdf files in `onActivityResult`. But path is showing

> /content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/8828

. 
web view is not loading . I tried by hardcoding value 
Here is my code :

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true)
    startActivityForResult(intent, PDF_EXPLORER_REQUEST_CODE)
```

and in onActivityResult

```
val mImageUri = data.data.path   
webview.loadUrl(mImageUri.toString())
```

I tries by getting actual path of pdf in phone `webview.loadUrl(/storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy.pdf)`

if I hardcode some url like `htts://www.goole.com` webview is loading. But not loading my local pdfs.

how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri)

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri Load the path instead.

Comment: A webview cannot display a pdf file to begin with. Like notepad on windows either ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Webview** cant load local(sdcard) pdf file, 
If you want to load sdcard pdf file you can use **third party lib** for it

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

or

You can use this method if you want

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087727/4951663